# Which mkv player for iPad mini?

Tags: ipad, video

What video player for iPad mini supports mkv format best?

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLC player.

Or, you can use Handbrake to convert MKV to MP4. Here is a [helpful article on downloading and using Handbrake.](http://www.dvd-on-ipadmini.com/convert-mkv-to-ipadmini-free.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck using FileBrowser on the iPad - primarily useful for streaming files from a network share.